# Terminal deleting additional letters, submitting different typed in letters and returning different previous commands

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal

I'm trying to use my terminal to play around with some code (particle.io), I've never used it much before but it's acting in strange way that's making it near impossible to use, there's three things I've noticed:

1. Firstly, if I go back to a previous command (by pressing up) it's changed slightly.

For example here it's removed a '"' from the 147.

[image]

2. Then if I key backwards and try to change this param or anything in the text when I delete and retype words it removes letters from both sides of the cursor.
3. Finally when I hit submit some slightly different is submitted, for example in that picture I tried typing hundred, then it got modified and then changed again on submit.

I was wondering if anyone knew what on earth is going on with my terminal, I'm up-to-date on the latest El Capitan.

Thanks!

Edit:

`echo $SHELL` gives `/bin/bash`

Comment: First off what enumerator are you using, default Terminal Mac app? Which shell, `echo $SHELL`? It might also helpful if you tell use more of the code. I would recommend [FISH](http://fishshell.com) if you already aren't using it, it's very beginner friendly, but I'm sure many would disagree.

Comment: `echo $SHELL` gives `/bin/bash`, it also it is the Terminal Mac app yes. It's all code that doing it, not just this one. I'll edit the question with the contents of the bash file too.